# Разделить строку по символу и добавить сам символ в массив

Tags: c#, строки

Мне нужно разделить строку по символу при этом занести всё это в массив в месте с разделителем имею код:

```
string[] words = message.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

но мне нужно чтобы в массиве были еще и `\n`

Comment: Регулярные выражения используй. Вот так попробуй: `Regex.Split(message, "(\n)");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

альтернативный способ - Regex, но он более сложный https://regex101.com/r/5ha92x/2

```
var pattern = "[^\\n]+\\n?";
var matches = Regex.Matches(message, pattern);
var words = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m=>m.Value).ToArray();
```

этот вариант сохраняет все `\n` как есть, но более тяжелый по производительности

Answer (score 1):

попробуй использовать это:
дает подобный результат но добавляет '\n' в конец каждой строки

```
string[] words = message
                  .Split('\n')
                  .Where(s=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                  .Select(s => s + '\n')
                  .ToArray();
```

Comment: @Kirill Meøw если не боишься лишнего '\n' в конце - кажется это то что тебе нужно